# syntax error while trying to update time_out in hours table

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to update the time_out time to the last id where users time_in was captured, the following code of mine is giving me this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

here is my logout.php

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
}   

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$dt = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");      
$id = $_SESSION['MEMBER_ID'];
$sql = "UPDATE hours SET time_out = '".$dt."' WHERE member_id IN (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = '".$id."'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    //Unset the variables stored in session
    unset($_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['LOGIN_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['PASS']);
```

here is the schema

```
 `hours_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `team` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `time_in` datetime NOT NULL,
  `time_out` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    unset($_SESSION['TEAM']);
```

what could be wrong in this query someone.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have closed the round brackets in your query like this?

```
$sql = "UPDATE hours SET time_out = '".$dt."' WHERE member_id IN (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = '".$id."')";
```

**Note:** Stop using deprecated mysql_* versions. There are better alternatives likes mysqli or pdo

**EDIT**

With single query you can fix your issue like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE hours SET time_out = '".$dt."' WHERE member_id IN (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = '".$id."') AS t)";
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: ah you are right but now another error comes which is You can't specify target table 'hours' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @lalthung I've added my edited answer to update records in single query, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: mate i get this error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE member_id = '1') AS t)' at line 1

Comment: Ohh Sorry my mistake, `FROM` tag was missing; updated the answer. Pls check and let me know

Comment: ok it is updating but only for member_id 1, i tried to login with member_id 2 the time_out  remails 00:00:00:00 :)  how could this be fixed?

Comment: lol, now for that we have to debug the code as well as check what's the data present in the table

Comment: I've one question, here you are doing `WHERE member_id IN` but in your sub query you are selecting ` MAX(hours_id)`. how and why?

Comment: well let me tell you what actually im trying to achieve, when user logs in on a new day i insert his login to hours table which has time_in and time_out so while logging in a new id is generated and time_in is inserted now when they logout i wish to update time_out of that users which ever is the last id in hours table

Comment: So every time login new record will get inserted for my member id with time_in, Now you want to update time_out in the most recent record of my memer_id?

Comment: new records are inserted only id its a new day, supposing today is 30 and there already is time_in then more wont get inserted and yes only on the most recent inserted id in hours table of a user the  time_out should update

Comment: In that case why you are looking for `MAX(hours_id)`? simply pass today's date and update the `time_out`. If the record with my `member_id` and today's `time_in` exist then update `time_out`. Correct me if there are any other functionality catch

Comment: glad to hear that :) can you please accept my answer and up-vote it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here your solution you forgot to complete bracket for inner query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE hours SET time_out = '".$dt."' WHERE member_id IN (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = '".$id."')";
```

Try above code it will work.
Suggestion stop using old functions start work on  MySQLi .[Reference for  MySQLi](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp)

Comment: you are right mate thanks but i face another issue which stats You can't specify target table 'hours' for update in FROM clause what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

This should be your **sql**

```
$sql="UPDATE hours SET time_out = '".$dt."' WHERE member_id IN (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = '".$id."')";
```

Comment: thanks guys now i have new error which is You can't specify target table 'hours' for update in FROM clause what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query and try again,i hope it will work

```html
$sql = "UPDATE hours SET time_out = '$dt' WHERE member_id IN (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = '$id'";
```

Comment: thanks now a new error which is You can't specify target table 'hours' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
}   

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$dt = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");      
$id = $_SESSION['MEMBER_ID'];
$sql = "UPDATE hours SET time_out = '".$dt."' WHERE member_id IN (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = '".$id."')";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    //Unset the variables stored in session
    unset($_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['LOGIN_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['PASS']);
```